# Can re-entrant locking mechanism be achieved in Java using Synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Is there a way of using synchronized methods to create a mechanism for re-entrant locks?

Since a synchronized method wont let 2 Threads to enter the critical section together i think it is not possible. Could anyone provide me some insight ?

Suppose i extended re-entrant property to Reader-Writer problem where multiple readers can have lock on same Object but Writer locks are exclusive.

Can we achieve this functionality using synchronized methods?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question, but a re-entrant lock is a lock that you can acquire a second time when you already hold it (as opposed to a non-re-entrant lock, that would just block at that point).

Synchronized blocks in Java have this property: A thread that already holds a lock can enter the block.

Without this, it would be very hard to code proper execution paths, as you could not have one synchronized method of an object call another.

Comment: I don't think there's any particular need for one synchronised method to call another. Indeed, it's probably a good idea if that doesn't happen.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Why?

Answer (score 2):

In the following code

```
public class Foo {
    public synchronized void bar() { 
        zoop();
    }

    public synchronized void zoop() {}
}
```

If a `Thread` calls

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();
```

You have a reentrant lock, because the `Thread` owns the `Foo` object monitor and then reacquires it when it calls `zoop()` inside `bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear that you understand what 're-entrant' actually means. It means you can re-acquire a lock you already hold without being blocked on it. `synchronized` already has the re-entrancy property.

Comment: The word "re-entrant" actually comes from the meaning "re-enter" as in a method being able to be re-entered by another "thread" at the same time another "thread" is working on it.  It actually was used at a time when we were not talking about parallel/concurrent execution but single core multiple thread systems.